# Android, Button in Listview, not associated with correct row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, getview

I have a listview containing a textview I would like to click on.

I have managed to make this, but no matter which row's textview I click on it's like I clicked on the bottom row's.

For example, when I click on my textview in row 2, it acts as if I clicked on my textview in the bottom row of my screen.

It doesn't seem to matter which row's textview I click on, it's always as if I click on the last loaded position's textview.

From reading other related questions, googling, and running my debugger, I suspect it has to do with the fact that the row on the bottom of the screen was the last position loaded and when I click on something it uses that positions clicklisteners. From what I've seen I need to make use of tags to resolve this, but I couldn't quite understand how to apply the tags and how to use the tag's position in my code.

Here is my custom arrayadapter's getView method and my listeners:

```
    @Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    question = (Question) getItem(position);

    // Get or create cached eventView
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(mResourceId, null);
        questionView = new QuestionListItemHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(questionView);
    }
    else {
        questionView = (QuestionListItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Fill Data in each row
    fillData();

    // Setup click listeners for row's clickable items
    setListeners();

    return convertView;
}
```

and my listener:

```
    private void setListeners(){
    questionView.getAskedByTextView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (context, ProfileActivity.class);
            // Seems "question" is based off position in getView
            // Need some way to have the "question" be the one for the
            // Position of the row I clicked on, not the last row...
            ParseUser u = question.getUser();

            intent.putExtra("User", u.getObjectId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    questionView.getFollowButton().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wantAnswerActivity();
        }
    });
}
```

How can I make it so that the button or textview I click on is associated with the correct row position?

Comment: use `setTag` ans `getTag`. `questionView.getAskedByTextView().setTag(question)` and use `getTag` in `onClick` similarly for button. Also why do you listeners in a separate method. you can have them in getView itself

Comment: @Raghunandan Still didn't work... I put         questionView.getAskedByTextView().setTag(question);
in getView,
and
 Question q = (Question) questionView.getAskedByTextView().getTag();
                ParseUser u = q.getUser();
in my button listener

Comment: It should work. U need to understand how listview recyclesvviews

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the listeners in getView itself only to get correct content.If you declare it in outside of getView.You can't able to get exact onClick Listeners for that particular position.

```
@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
question = (Question) getItem(position);

// Get or create cached eventView
if(convertView == null){
    convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(mResourceId, null);
    questionView = new QuestionListItemHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(questionView);
}
else {
    questionView = (QuestionListItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

// Fill Data in each row
fillData();
questionView.getAskedByTextView().setOnClickListener(new                                        View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (context, ProfileActivity.class);
        // Seems "question" is based off position in getView
        // Need some way to have the "question" be the one for the
        // Position of the row I clicked on, not the last row...
        ParseUser u = question.getUser();

        intent.putExtra("User", u.getObjectId());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});

questionView.getFollowButton().setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        wantAnswerActivity();
    }
});
}
 // Setup click listeners for row's clickable items

 return convertView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For `ListView` , the `setOnItemClickListener()` should do it.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  position, long id) {

if(position==0)
   //row 1 clicked

}
```

Comment: I have this code in my activity, but this is for when I click the whole row, which works as I want. Im trying to click on a button in the row, not the row itself